# Bound on the degree of the solution

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be an algebraically closed field. We have a system of $d$ linear equations in $d+1$ variables denoted by $u_0,\ldots,u_d$. The coefficients belongs to $\mathbb{K}[x]$ and the system is consistent so there exists a solution.

$u_0 +u_1 h_{1}^{1}+\ldots+u_d h_{d}^{1}=0 $

$u_0 +u_1 h_{1}^{2}+\ldots+u_d h_{d}^{2}=0 $

$\vdots$

$u_0 +u_1 h_{1}^{d}+\ldots+u_d h_{d}^{d}=0 $
where $h_{i}^{j}\in \mathbb{K}[x]$.

So we have $d$ equations.

For each equation we put a degree bound that is $e_j =max\{deg \ h_{i}^{j}\}i\in{1\ldots d}$.

I want a bound on the degree for the solution of the system of linear equations in terms of $e_j, d$.  Are this results known in the literature? Can anyone please cite me a reference or a proof?

Comment: Why do you think that the solution is polynomial? Cramer's rule tells differently.

Comment: The solution could be in $\mathbb{K}(x)$ then we could multiply by the greatest common divisor of the denominators. All I want is some bound to the degree of the solution.

Comment: Let $H_n$ be the upper square part of $H$. Then with $u_0=\det(H_n)$ and using the adjunkt (transpose of co-factor matrix) $(u_1,...,u_n)^T=-H_n^\#\mathbf1$ you get a polynomial solution with obvious degree bound. Per assumption it also satisfies the last equation.

Comment: It's a $(d+1)xd$ matrix so you mean I will take the first $d$ equations? I don't get why $u_0= det(H_n)$ also transpose of co-factor is by Cramer rule?

Comment: Yes, this all can be explained by Cramer. Re-arrange the equations if necessary so that the first $n$ are independent.